# Should I use the Disability Confident Scheme to get an interview?

Tags: interviewing, united-kingdom, disability

I am applying for an assistant professor position at a university in the UK. This is a very competitive position and my chances of getting it are quite small. I can however be guarantied an interview (if I meet 'the minimum essential criteria') because the university takes part in the 'Disability Confident Scheme' and I am diabetic (type 1). I believe that I will meet these criteria, but expect that there will be many applicants with a stronger resume than mine. I am afraid that if I tick the 'Disability Confident Scheme' box, I will get an interview, but will not actually be considered for the job. Is that a risk or is the employer free to interpret 'minimum essential criteria' loosely?

I am quite happy to disclose my 'disability' if it helps me get the job, but I do not want an empty interview. I don't really understand this 'Disability Confident Scheme'. What does it imply to opt out?

For more context: I live in Germany and going to the interview will be expensive and time-consuming. I don't want to go there unless I actually have a chance of getting the job.

Comment: I ticked that box once and got refused the interview for doing so. Now, I can't say whether your prospective employer will be like Lloyds, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @Studoku On what grounds did they refuse the interview? What did they say?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I googled 'Uk Disability Confident Scheme diabetes type 1' and found multiple pages telling me that yes, it is. Should I write to the university to check with them?

Comment: You put disability in quotes, so although diabetes type 1 is considered a disability in certain circumstances (I think) I'm assuming you don't actually consider yourself as 'disabled' by the usual defintion, so would you be using this as a technicality to get an interview? (I also have a condition that is technically a disability but don't consider myself disabled either!. & don't know if I would tick that box :s) Do you think you have a chance at the job if interviewed since there are "many applicants with a stronger resume than yours", do you feel you can talk you way in?

Comment: @StevenMathey It took two weeks of waiting for an interview, and another two of getting a response to be told literally nothing besides that they weren't offering me an interview. Why, are you privy to information I'm not?

Comment: @Studoku It seems like Steven was just asking whether your prospective employer gave a reason for not going ahead.

Comment: I know German law has a clause which says large employers need to have a certain percentage of disabled employees, so jobs adverts have a sentence like 'disabled applicants will be favored'. If a similar law exists in the UK they might even give you the job if other applicants have a stronger resume than you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main question is,

> Do you think you have a better chance of getting a job if the person meets you?

In a normal circumstance, I'd say just go for it, interview practice is a great help anyway as I assume you're a recent graduate, but you've mentioned it's costly to get there so it's probably not the best place to practice!

In general, the scheme is there to help candidates that may not look great on paper *because of* the disability. For example, if it has stopped you doing certain things which may mean you tick slightly fewer boxes (but still meet the minimum requirements for the job).  It's essentially meant to level the playing-field for those with a disability: [Guaranteed Interview Scheme](https://www.pcs.org.uk/guaranteed-interview-scheme"pcs.org").

**Warning Opinion ahead**:

Personally, I also qualify for the scheme as I am dyslexic. However, I do not think my disability impacts my job prospects. For me personally, I don't feel I need to level the playing-field. Just to clarify though, I'm a techy. If I decided on a career in journalism it may be different. Maybe fresh out of uni, if I was job searching and needed the practice, I would have used the scheme, but now I pass right by that tick box as, like you, I don't want to waste my time with pointless interviews. (Although I do also somewhat hypocritically preach that no interview is pointless and they are all good practice).

**TL:DR**

**The scheme is designed for those who are at a disadvantage in applying for jobs due to their disability, if you don't think this is you, submit your application without and get the interview (or not) on the merit of that.**

Answer (score 3):

I believe the point of the scheme is that people with a disability are often more compelling potential employees in person than they appear on paper. The scheme isn't perfect but it can mitigate some of the disadvantages that confront people with a disability during the job hunting process.

> "going to the interview will be expensive and time-consuming. I don't want to go there unless I actually have a chance of getting the job."

If you are interviewed and meet the person specification then you have a chance of getting the job.

.... we can't tell you if you have a *good* chance or not but there is a chance.